# Why do I get two UberPool products in the APIs?

Tags: uber-api

I get two UberPool products in the following APIs:

```
api.uber.com/v1/estimates/time
api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price
api.uber.com/v1/products
```

Why do I get two products? How are they different?

Example response:

Url:

```
api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price
```

Response:

```
{
  "prices": [
    {
      "localized_display_name": "uberPOOL",
      "high_estimate": 33,
      "minimum": null,
      "duration": 0,
      "estimate": "₹32.50",
      "distance": 0,
      "display_name": "uberPOOL",
      "product_id": "e0178e76-b13f-4ae6-9f72-6acadbb450c5",
      "low_estimate": 32,
      "surge_multiplier": 1,
      "currency_code": "INR"
    },
    {
      "localized_display_name": "uberPOOL",
      "high_estimate": 51,
      "minimum": null,
      "duration": 0,
      "estimate": "Unavailable",
      "distance": 0,
      "display_name": "uberPOOL",
      "product_id": "f855a84b-a0ec-40d8-a455-fb0d2db58089",
      "low_estimate": 50,
      "surge_multiplier": 1,
      "currency_code": "INR"
    },
    {
      "localized_display_name": "uberGO",
      "high_estimate": 50,
      "minimum": 50,
      "duration": 0,
      "estimate": "₹50",
      "distance": 0,
      "display_name": "uberGO",
      "product_id": "18ba4578-b11b-49a6-a992-a132f540b027",
      "low_estimate": 50,
      "surge_multiplier": 1,
      "currency_code": "INR"
    }
    ....
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: @AshishChopra not yet. Still waiting for a reply on my comments on the two answers below.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Uber sometimes offers many products in a given location, and they're all returned from those two endpoints.

To expound on that... according to the [docs](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-products), this is normal:

> The Products endpoint returns information about the Uber products
>   offered at a given location. The response includes the display name
>   and other details about each product, and lists the products in the
>   proper display order.
>
> Some products, such as uberEATS, are not returned by this endpoint.
>   We'll soon be making uberPOOL available in this endpoint.

Particularly: **We'll soon be making uberPOOL available in this endpoint.** It seems that time has come.

The same goes for the [estimates endpoint](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-estimates-price).

> The Price Estimates endpoint returns an estimated price range for each
>   product offered at a given location.

---

> How are they different?

Uber offers different types of services in different countries.

[UberGo](http://www.fonearena.com/blog/123078/ubergo-cheaper-version-of-uberx-launched-in-india.html) is a cheaper version of UberX that seems to be specific to India.

[UberPool](https://help.uber.com/h/5d3fa7d0-9831-4ead-b4f4-0299eb443ea2) is fairly straight forward in that it's a carpooling service offered to those who wish to split the fare with others that are heading in the same destination.

Since services vary by location, it's best to research them individually when constructing a service that's consuming the Uber API.

Comment: We'll update our documentation to remove the following sentence: "We'll soon be making uberPOOL available in this endpoint." Thanks for flagging.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this does not answer how are the two products different and why do they show two different products.

Comment: The latter of your statement is actually answered here. Specifically: **The Products endpoint returns information about the Uber products offered at a given location**. Regarding how they are different, I can elaborate more, but it's best to do research on the services that Uber offers when developing a service that consumes their API.

Comment: Hi, sorry I missed this comment since I did not get a notification for it. Apologies for that. I did research the Uber Products for the area I'm in and I see just one UberPool product in the Uber app. The only explanation I can think of it is that one of them is for 1 passenger and the other is for two passengers. But then why would the product ids be different for the two?

Comment: @Alec Can you tell me how we can change the uberPool seat capacity (1 or 2)from Uber iOS sdk? I didn't find anything in UBSDKRideParameters. I found seat_count in   POST /v1/requests/estimate but not in iOS sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the report. This is a known issue and we're working on a fix. In the meantime, you can use either uberPOOL product that is surfaced.

Comment: The price estimates on both of them vary by a lot though. Also, is there a support for mentioning whether there'll be one or two riders availing uberPool?

Comment: What part of this is an issue? The multiple services being returned by then endpoints that the OP si hitting? The documentation suggests that this is normal.

Comment: @Seth I am sorry for the late response. I did not get notification for the comments so missed them.
I'll try to explain in more details. So I'm calling the APIs from India. If I open the uber app, as a user I just see one UberPool option.
https://postimg.org/image/fcxzph1y9/

But from the API I get two of them. Now which of the two options correspond to the option I see in the Uber App. Since that is what I would want end users to see.